# Type Initialization Failed In Non-Static Class

Tags: c#, static

I've got this nagging issue that I need to fix for a major project of mine. I'm trying to reference a static variable (owned by a static class) from a non-static class. When I try to do this, it throws the exception 'The type initializer for 'Eternal_Continent.PSTATS' threw an exception.'

The inner exception reads

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's my PSTATS class

```
public static class PSTATS
    {
        static Locations Locations;
        public static string name = "";
        public static int health = 100;
        public static int dmg = 1;
        public static int mana = 100;
        public static int hpotion = 3;
        public static int mpotion = 3;
        public static int def = 1;
        public static int level = 1;
        public static int xp = 0;
        public static float tradereward = 1.0f;
        public static string employer = "Knight Artemis";
        public static misc.Quest currentquest;
        public static misc.NPC currentnpc = null;
        public static int npcindex = 0;
        public static misc.Location currentlocation = Locations.Ardimir;
        public static string reward = "Charisma + 1";
        public static bool finding = false;
        public static string questreward = "G";
        public static int kills = 0;
        public static int gold = 0;
        // Has found item

        public static bool found = false;

        //Has job

        public static bool job = false;
        public static int reqkills = 0;
        public static int reqgold = 0;
        public static int dex = 1;
        public static int str = 1;
        public static int itl = 1;
        public static int cha = 1;

        public static bool existingdialog = false;
    }
```

And here's the non-static class calling it

```
public class Weapon
        {
            #region
            public Weapon(string name, string desc, int dmg, int mana)
            {

                Name = name;
                Desc = desc;
                Dmg = Convert.ToInt32(dmg * (PSTATS.level / 0.9));
                Manausage = mana;
            }
            public int Manausage;
            public int manausage
            {
                get
                {
                    return Manausage;
                }
                set
                {
                    Manausage = value;
                }
            }
            public string Name;
            public string name
            {
                get
                {
                    return Name;
                }
                set
                {
                    Name = value;
                }
            }
            public string Desc;
            public string desc
            {
                get
                {
                    return Desc;
                }
                set
                {
                    Desc = value;
                }
            }
            public int Dmg;
            public int dmg
            {
                get
                {
                    return Dmg;
                }
                set
                {
                    Dmg = Convert.ToInt32(value * (PSTATS.level / 0.9));
                }
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we're still missing some of your code, but my gut tells me it has to do with the first member in your PSTATS class called `Locations`.  It would appear that `Locations` is an enum which means you shouldn't need a reference to it.  Try removing that member and perhaps post the code pertaining to `misc` and the `Locations` enum.

Comment: Thanks Trent, I used both your's and mn's answer. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the exact code you have creating the two classes.
I then created an object in main:  Weapon w = new Weapon("n", "d", 6, 3);
It was successful and there were no problems using the static PSTATS variables.

The only changes I made were deleting Locations and misc variables in PSTAT which are not needed for creating a Weapon and allowed me to run the test.

Comment: Thanks mn, it's all fine now.